# Time Series using STS( Basic Structural Model)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am using Basic Structs to forecast my time series. My forecast is exactly overlapping my data. I am sure no model can predict with 100% accuracy. I know I am missing something, can someone point me what the mistake is? My data and code are given below.

As you can see, when I run the below code, I get the following image, which shows that my model is too good.

[image]

```
Year  <- c(2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 
           2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
           2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
           2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
           2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 
           2012, 2012, 2013, 2013)
Month <- c(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
           12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
           8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2) 

base.oil<-c(995,1090,1290,1430,1440,1420,1175,840,730,625,570,510,500,575,680,745,765,780,780,780,795,790,790,865,920,960,960,960,960,975,970,988,1035,1095,1165,1270,1300,1310,1370,1370,1353,1245,1172.5,1070,1060,1070,1085,1140,1197.5,1215,1180,1025,1025,1022.5,1000,960,942.5,855,857.5)


gl<- data.frame(Year = Year, Month = Month, base.oil=base.oil)


#convert the dataset to a Time Series(TS) object
gl.ts<-ts(gl,start=c(2008,4),end=c(2013,2),frequency=12)

#Removing outliers in 2008 data, Selecting data only from 2009 for analysis
gl.train<-window(gl.ts,start=c(2009,1),end=c(2012,3))


#Creating a test set
gl.test<-window(gl.ts,start=c(2012,4))


#Creating a list of models--using only StructTS
models <- list(
  mod_sts= StructTS(gl.train[,3])
)
#Forecast on Test Dataset
forecasts <- lapply(models, forecast, 11)


par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
for(f in forecasts){
  plot(f)
  lines(gl.test[,3], col='red')
}

#Overlapping StructTS over the training data
plot(gl.train[,3],main="Overlapping StructTS over the training data",ylab="Oil Prices")
lines(fitted(forecasts$mod_sts),col="red")
```

**EDIT:**
On the test set, it performs better compared to other models I tried
Error Stats and plots are given below
[image]

Comment: How does the model perform on the test set?

Comment: @MattReichenbach: I have added the info in edits, please check